# Click anywhere remove class jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, responsive

I am trying to take a mobile open menu and close it by clicking anywhere except for the actual navigation items.

Here is my HTML

```
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a title="About Riad Kilani - Front End Developer" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a title="Portfolio of Riad Kilani - Front End Developer" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a title="Front End Development News and Tutorials from Riad Kilani" href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a title="Contact Riad Kilani" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  <section id="featured">
    <a href="#" class="mobile-button"><i class="fa fa-bars">&nbsp;Site Name</i></a>
  </section>
</div>
```

And Here is my JS

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".mobile-button").click(function() {
    $("#content").addClass("mobile-open");
  });

  $(document).click(function(event){
    if (event.target.id === 'site-nav') {
    } else {
        $("#content").removeClass("mobile-open"); 
    }                   
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: on which event you want to remove the class "mobile-open"?

Comment: `event.target.id === 'site-nav` In your html site-nav is class name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I will add to your links class, e.g. `class="link"`:

```
<nav class="site-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="link" title="About Riad Kilani - Front End Developer" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" title="Portfolio of Riad Kilani - Front End Developer" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" title="Front End Development News and Tutorials from Riad Kilani" href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a class="link" title="Contact Riad Kilani" href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="content">
  <section id="featured">
    <a href="#" class="mobile-button"><i class="fa fa-bars">&nbsp;Site Name</i></a>
  </section>
</div>
```

After that, try below jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".mobile-button").click(function(event) {
        $("#content").addClass("mobile-open");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function(event){
        if (!$(event.target).hasClass('link')) {
            $("#content").removeClass("mobile-open");
        }
    });
});
```

I made jsFiddler for that so you can check if that is what you want - https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/8261/.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was able to get it working without class="link" too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".mobile-button").click(function () {
        $("#content").addClass("mobile-open");
    });

     $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('.site-nav').length) {
            $("#content").removeClass("mobile-open");
        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JQuery:

```
*:not(.site-nav).click(fuction() {
  // code that does stuff
});
```

To select *everything* except `.site-nav`.